# Efficiently find "record high" values

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, algorithm, ruby-on-rails-4, query-optimization

I'm trying to figure out an efficient way to identify the set of "record high" values from a set of data. This is more complicated than just finding the maximum value since I want to find all values that were the maximum/record high value at the time they were recorded. So to simplify the problem as much as possible, imagine a model/database table like:

```
Temperatures(date, value)
```

with values like:

```
*1/1/2001: 79
*1/2/2001: 81
1/3/2001: 81
1/4/2001: 80
*1/5/2001: 82
1/6/2001: 81
*1/7/2001: 90
```

I'm trying to find a query that would help identified the starred ("*") records above as "records". Either a rails finder or raw sql statement would work fine. The best I've gotten so far is a query that will tell me if a given value is a record, but that doesn't scale very well.

Comment: I don't think it can be translated easily to SQL, but sort according to date and iterate while maintaining maximal value should do the trick. Could be infeasible though if your data is too large, what's the scale of your data? And how often do you need to perform this query?

Comment: What about `SELECT [Date], MAX([Value]) FROM Temperatures GROUP BY [Date]`? I'm making assumptions about your data, which is why this is a comment, not an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `not exists` to select rows where another row with both a higher value and earlier date does not exist

```
select date, value
from mytable t1
where not exists (
    select 1 from mytable t2
    where t2.value >= t1.value
    and t2.date < t1.date
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a group by would work fine. Try this

```
SELECT MAX(Temperature), Date
FROM dbo.Temperatures
GROUP BY Date
```

Answer (score 0):

In Standard-SQL:

```
with temp (d, t, r) as                             
(select d, t, row_number() over (order by d)       
 from t),                                    
     data (d, t, r) as                             
(select d, t, r                                    
 from   temp                                       
 where  r = 1                                      
 union  all                                        
 select case when t.t > d.t then t.d else d.d end, 
        case when t.t > d.t then t.t else d.t end, 
        t.r                                        
 from   temp t                                     
 inner  join data d on d.r+1 = t.r)                
select min(d), min(t)                              
from   data                                        
group  by d, t
```